# Python logging config to file AND stdout: not possible to use different log levels

Tags: python, file, ubuntu, logging

Under Ubuntu I experiencetd that the usage of different debug levels for loggers to stdout and to file is not possible. In my Windows environment (Spyder with Anacosna) it works as expected. Please see my example code. Anyone has an idea what's wrong here?

This is my example code:

```py
import logging
#from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
logfile = "log.log"
levels =('NOTSET', 'DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'ERROR', 'CRITICAL')
dateformat = '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
strformat = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s in %(funcName)s at %(lineno)s: %(message)s'
formatter = logging.Formatter(strformat,datefmt=dateformat)

for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
    logging.root.removeHandler(handler)

logging.basicConfig(
    format = strformat,
    datefmt = dateformat,
    force = True,
    level = logging.WARNING,
    )
if logfile:
    print(f"Creating {logfile}")
    fh = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
    #fh = RotatingFileHandler(logfile, maxBytes=(1000), backupCount=1)
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    logging.getLogger('').addHandler(fh)
logging.debug(f"logging level is set to {levels[logging.root.level//10]}")
logging.warning("level warning test")
```

I would expect to see the debug level message in the file but this is not the case.
I see the warning in both, stdout and the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Do you need the logging module versions? How can I display the version?

Comment: Why are you mucking around with `logging.root` at all, let alone before you call `logging.basicConfig`? The logger itself is set to `WARNING`, so I wouldn't expect it to be passed to *any* of its handlers.

Comment: If you think my answer is correct and helpful, you should mark it as accepted so that it will help to guide others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the flow of information in logging, documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow). Since the root logger's level is set to `WARNING`, it will not process `DEBUG` or `INFO` events, no matter what the levels are for any of the handlers attached to it.

Comment: Thanks @Vinay I skipped that part of the docu indeed... I have changed the example code and it works now as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code according to @Vinay's answer. Now I find the expected behavior

```py
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
logfile = "log.log"
levels =('NOTSET', 'DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'ERROR', 'CRITICAL')
dateformat = '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
strformat = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s in %(funcName)s:%(lineno)s: %(message)s'
formatter = logging.Formatter(strformat,datefmt=dateformat)

logging.basicConfig(
        format = strformat,
        datefmt = dateformat,
        force = True,
        level = logging.DEBUG,
        )

logger = logging.getLogger('test_app')
for handler in logger.root.handlers[:]:
        logger.root.removeHandler(handler)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)
if logfile:
        #fh = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
        fh = RotatingFileHandler(logfile, maxBytes=(1000), backupCount=3)
        fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        fh.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(fh)

logger.debug(f"logging level is set to {levels[logging.root.level//10]}")
logger.debug("in logfile only")
logger.warning("In both, console and logfile")
logger.error("in both")

logger2=logging.getLogger('test_app')
logger2.debug("logger2 in logfile only")
logger2.warning("logger2 in both, console and logfile")
```